# Checkmark in table disappearing only after second touch on device

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios5, ios-simulator

I got the checkmarks appearing and disappearing correctly when scrolling and it works perfectly on simulator.

However on the device, a 4s, the touch to make the checkmark disappear again does not work properly. Meaning, I need to touch the row, which I want the checkmark to disappear twice. Only after the second touch the checkmark disappears.

Furthermore all selected columns remain with the blue background until I touch them again.

So here is the sequence (on the device):

1. touch row is selected, blue background, checkmark appears
2. touch on the same row blue background disappears, checkmark remains
3. touch on the same row, checkmark disappears, blue background

What I definitely need, is that the checkmark disappears, as soon as I touch the row again, actually the behavior I am having on the simulator.

The background I guess I am able to control via the didDeselectRow method. However, I struggle with imagining, how to control the checkmark issue. Any ideas??

Here is the code from the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSInteger thisCardID;
NSInteger thisCardIndex;
NSString *cellValue;

UITableViewCell *thisCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cellValue = thisCell.textLabel.text;

if(searching) {             
    thisCardID = [[self.aCopyOfCardIDArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] integerValue];
    thisCardIndex = [self.aCopyOfCardIDArray indexOfObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:thisCardID]];
    if (thisCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {            
        [self.searchedSelectedRowArray replaceObjectAtIndex:thisCardIndex withObject:@"YES"];
        thisCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [self.searchedSelectedCardIDs addObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger :thisCardID]];
    }
    else {
        [self.searchedSelectedRowArray replaceObjectAtIndex:thisCardIndex withObject:@"NO"];
        thisCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [self.searchedSelectedCardIDs removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:thisCardID]];
    }

} 
else {
    thisCardIndex = [self.tempCardArray indexOfObject:cellValue];

    if (thisCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {            
        [self.selectedRowArray replaceObjectAtIndex:thisCardIndex withObject:@"YES"];
        thisCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [self.selectedCardIDs addObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger :thisCardID]];
    }
    else {
        [self.selectedRowArray replaceObjectAtIndex:thisCardIndex withObject:@"NO"];
        thisCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [self.selectedCardIDs removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:thisCardID]];
    }
}


}
```

To make sure I am making myself clear, I added some screenshots:

[image: Table before selecting a row]

[image: Table after touching the row the first time]

[image: Table after touching the same row again]

[image: Table after I multi selected some rows and touched some rows again to deselect]

Comment: what *we* definitely need, is some code!

Comment: of course, sorry guys... edited my question... thx for the reminder... :-)

Comment: If it helps you can turn the blue off by setting your UITableViewCell selectionStyle property to UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone.  Then it won't show the blue when you touch it.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I tried this, but it did not change the behavior. In simulator it still does what it is supposed and on the device it does not. I just checked the version: Device is 5.0.1 and I run it on simulator 4.3

Comment: Alright, just as I wrote my comment above, I realized, that the different behavior might come from using simulator 4.3 instead of 5, and here we go. The simulator in 5 is acting as my iPhone 4 with the iOS 5 installed. I actually thought the simulator version is reflecting the device and not the iOS. So Simulator 4.x is for iOS 4 code and Simulator 5.x for iOS 5, correct? But that still leaves me with the checkmark and blue background problem... at least I have a consistency :-) Any suggestions highly appreciated, thankx

Comment: Ok, figured out, that didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called only every 2nd touch for some reason. Independent if the row is selected or not, it always takes 2 touches to actually receive the event in the code. I have debugged it. I imagine, that I miss some property which is the culprit of all that? Anyway, time to sleep now and let's check it out after a nice weekend of Tai Chi and Kung Fu :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was to early to go to sleep and Heureka, it's the didDeselectRowAtIndexPath which does the magic. That's why the second touch is not recognized by the didSelect... method. Logical, if you know it :-)
Now it's time to count sheeps...

Here the code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *thisCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
thisCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
thisCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```